# GraphQL Explorer not working with Express Sessions

Tags: typescript, express, session, graphql, express-graphql

I'm trying to create a login system with GraphQL and Express, but the sessions aren't being saved. Whenever I log in, `req.session.userId` stays undefined.

My code:

```
(async () => {
    await connect(process.env.MONGO_URI!, { dbName: "example" });

    const app = express();

    app.use(
        cors({
            origin: [__clientUrl__, "https://studio.apollographql.com"],
            credentials: true
        })
    );

    app.use(
        session({
            name: "qid",
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET!,
            store: MongoStore.create({
                mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI,
                dbName: "example"
            }),
            saveUninitialized: false,
            resave: false,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 6.048e8,
                httpOnly: __prod__,
                sameSite: "lax",
                secure: __prod__
            }
        })
    );

    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [HelloResolver, UserResolver],
            validate: false
        }),
        context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })
    });

    await server.start();

    server.applyMiddleware({
        app,
        cors: {
            origin: [__clientUrl__, "https://studio.apollographql.com"],
            credentials: true
        }
    });

    app.listen(__port__, () =>
        console.log(
            ` Server started at http://localhost:${__port__}${server.graphqlPath}`
        )
    );
})();
```

TypeGraphQL Login Mutation:

```
    @Mutation(() => User, { nullable: true })
    public async login(
        @Arg("username") username: string,
        @Arg("password") password: string,
        @Ctx() { req }: Context
    ) {
        const user = await UserModel.findOne(
            username.includes("@") ? { email: username } : { username }
        );
        if (!user) return;

        if (!(await verify(user.password, password))) return;

        req.session.userId = user._id;

        return user;
    }
```

I also enabled cookies in the GraphQL Explorer and set these headings:
[image: Headers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and realized I need to write this when you're creating the ApolloServer instance:

```
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [HelloResolver, UserResolver],
            validate: false
        }),
        context: ({ req, res }) => {
>           res.header(
>               "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
>               "https://studio.apollographql.com"
>           );
>           res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

            return { req, res };
        }
    });
```

This allows cookies to be set in the GQL Explorer. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: why are you setting the cors twice?

Comment: Oh, I removed that. It wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

have you found a solution ?
You may try to use the "old" playgound by adding the plugin ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground when creating your server

```
plugins: [ ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(), ],
```

If this is working with the "old" playgroud, then the issue is in the graphqlstudio.

AFAIC, i'm facing cors issues with graphql studio, whatever the cors value I'm passing to  the server. SO I gave up graphql studio and returned to playground

Comment: No worries, I think I found a way that works. Thanks for the input!

Comment: would you mind sharing your code and settings? still issue with cors

Comment: you can dig around in https://github.com/mathletedev/teachersonly.com